# Want to get One Drive ID for document in Word add-on

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office-js, office-addins, office365-apps

I want to get a permanent Id for an Office 365 document from a Word add-on (to store in an external system).  The url returned from Office.context.document.url will change if the document is renamed or moved.

So far the only solution I have found is to extract the path from the URL and then use the graph api to get the file by path.

I am worried that this is a fragile solution.  In particular It do not know whether the format of the URL will always be the same (e.g. everything after 'Documents' is the path).

Can anyone either reassure me or provide a better solution?

```
https://MYDOMAIN-my.sharepoint.com/personal/MY_NAME_COM/Documents/afolder/auniquedoc.docx
```

Comment: There might be better solutions. Are you planning to use this id to re-access to the document in offline mode / or is it going to be used for detecting when the same document accesses the add-in again?

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for OfficeJS, but there is a more robust way of using Graph to get the unique ID instead of parsing the URL yourself. Use the ['shares' API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/shares-get?view=graph-rest-1.0). Essentially:

1. Start with the document URL.
2. Encode it in [url-safe base64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/shares-get?view=graph-rest-1.0#encoding-sharing-urls)
3. Prepend that with `u!`
4. Call `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/shares/u!EncodedUrl/driveItem`

Note that while a file's ID does stay the same if it gets renamed or moved within a drive, the ID changes if it gets moved to another drive.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

1. Store the file to a your own Document Library but not the OneDrive.
2. Enable the [document id services](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/enable-and-configure-unique-document-ids-ea7fee86-bd6f-4cc8-9365-8086e794c984).
3. Now the document id is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I do not see any way to retrieve the document id from  [OfficeJS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/office?view=office-js)